# Instantiate Bean on Demand With Runtime-Defined Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-context

In my application I would like to instantiate a class on demand and pass some runtime parameters to is as well as have Spring automatically fulfil any `@Autowired` dependencies. For example, the class I would like to instantiate on demand:

```
@Service
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class FileProcess implements Runnable
{
    @Autowired
    private MyDAO myDAO;

    private String configOne;

    private String configTwo;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
    }
}
```

The object `myDAO` exists already within the ApplicationContext and I would like Spring to fulfil this dependency for me. Indeed any instantiation of this class shouldn't really know the internals of `FileProcess` only that it requires the configuration parameters `configOne` and `configTwo`

To get an instance of `FileProcess` I have use the `getBean()` method of the `ApplicationContext` but I am unable to pass in only the configuration parameters:

```
final FileProcess fileProcess = this.applicationContext.getBean(FileProcess.class, configOne, configTwo)
```

This results in the error:

`Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities`

I have found that no matter what constructor I add to `FileProcess` I get the same error. I would like to only have to pass in the configuration parameters and not, in this case not an instance of `MyDAO`. Again, having to pass in an instance of MyDAO means the caller must have knowledge of the internals of `FileProcess` and in general must be aware of the scope of such beans.

Is there a way I can achieve this without having to resort to a `@Configuration` class and a `@Bean` annotated method?

Comment: Create setters for the config fields and a constructor for the Dao, then you can create it in a `@Bean` method.

Comment: I I have understood you correctly if I did that, I believe I could not use the `getBean()` method to automatically inject `MyDAO` because it results in a circular reference, and I don't want to pass in a DAO because I would need to know its scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be best off with a factory bean, like

```
@Bean
BiFunction<String, String, FileProcess> createFileProcess(MyDAO dao) {
    return (c1, c2) -> {
        FileProcess result = new FileProcess(dao) ;
        result.setConfig1(c1);
        result.setConfig2(c2);
        return result;
   };
}
```

This in a configuration class, and you can Autowire it to create the process object with your config values.

```
@Autowired
BiFunction<String, String, FileProcess> processFactory;
... 
FileProcess p = processFactory.apply("val1", "val2");
```

Comment: Although this is not how I have solved it, your answer was the basis for my solution. Above you have solved for my specific case and uses a `BiFunction` type I extended it further to sove for the general case. Instead of `BiFunction` I created a factory class with `getInstance`. The factory class is annotated as a service and I can use the `ApplicationContext.getBean()` within `getInstance` to autowire the dependencies.